# COM / Active X user control Can't embed interop types

Tags: c#, com, interop, activex

I'm currently trying to make use of the 'Adobe PDF Reader' Active X control in a windows form applications.

Adding this control to a form creates two new references in the project

AcroPDFLib (Name: Interop.AcroPDFLib)
AxAcroPDFLib (Name: AxInterop.AcroPDFLib)

and in the .csproj file I get two COM reference elements.

I've struggled to find documentation on what I'm now struggling with.

What I want to do is enabled 'Embed Interop Types' However, I am unable to do this.

I can set Embed interop types to true for AcroPDFLib. However the compiler tells me it still treats it as a reference since it is reference by AxAcroPdf and that is not embedded.

If I try to Embed AxAcroPdfLib, it says it can't because in my code I have to create an instance of AxAcroPdf, (which is the control that displays the pdf) and suggests I use the interface instead. However there is no interface to use. The interface from the COM Library (IAcroAXDocShim) is not implemented by AxAcroPdf but infact wrapped by it, AxAcroPDF has a private field of type IAcroAXDocShim.

So I can't see a way for me to embed either of this COM libraries, which I would like to do.

This is causing me issues as my build server can't build the project but it doesn't have these COM dll's and from I've been reading I shouldn't create a Nuget package from COM dll's. So I'm a bit lost on how to work around this

Comment: Hard to guess what the problem could be, it works just fine when I try it.  The *exact* compile error message and a code snippet is important to get help.

Comment: @HansPassant Hello! Thank you for attempting to help. What exactly did you try? When I do all this locally, I doesn't fail to build. I just cant embed the interop types and turn copy local to false, if I do that when I run the program if fails at runtime as it can't find the dll, because it actually wasn't embedded (it tells me in the output window when building).

Comment: How about using a dynamic type variable instead of Embed Interop Types? [dynamic (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic)